# Trying to understand adding to arrays in C when coming from C#

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I'm in a situation where I need to make a byte array buffer that I can update throughout the life a of program. If I have two C arrays

```
 unsigned char buffer[1400]; 
 unsigned char data[64];
```

the data array values will be changing continually through out the program and getting passed through various loops (64 will always be the max length) at which point a range of its values will be added to the buffer array. So for example say that the data array has 64 different hex values in it and I want to add to the buffer a certain range of these values. This is where I get stuck, my data array looks like this..

```
data[64] = {0x00, 0xeb, 0xff, etc...}
```

In C# I would do the following to select the range I want and add it to the buffer

```
buffer.AddRange(data.Skip(6).Take(30));
```

But I'm completely lost on how to do this in C. I am really new to the language, looking through SO I see people mentioning you would use realloc but I'm still trying to wrap my head around how that works. I would greatly appreciate some guidance, hopefully I have provided enough info. Thanks!

EDIT NOTE: The buffer arrays size of 1400 is just the actual max that it will ever be, technically it could be a dynamic range anywhere between there. Would setting its max even if it never reaches that much cause any sort of issue?

Comment: One thing to realize is, C arrays are very primitive, for example they have no runtime size, and they often degenerate to just pointers. It might help if you wrap the array and whatever size bookkeeping you have in a struct. Then you can add functions which take pointers to these structs, to manipulate them. Sort of like primitive OOP class thing.

Comment: I have been looking into structs, I seem to gather that they are some what similar to an object right? So the array would just be a "property" of the struct. I may be completely off base here though.

Comment: Struct is like a class with all public data members and no methods or inheritance (except with function pointers you can sort of add virtual methods, but that is a different, advanced subject).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want something like

```
 #include <string.h>
 ...
 /* sizeof data is 64 if data is an array[64] of (unsigned) char */
 memcpy (&buffer[6], data, sizeof data);
```

This copies all the 64 data octets to the 7th buffer byte and following. If you want to copy less data,

```
 memcpy (&buffer[6], &data[42], 3);
```

copies the three bytes starting with `data[42]`.

Comment: ok, so in the case of $data[42] it would be starting at the 42nd element in the array? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Almost. C starts counting at 0, so `&data[42]` is the address of the **43rd** element (which is equivalent to `data + 42`). Oh, and there's no concatenation here. It's addition. A pointer plus an integer n yields the address of element n (starting at 0).

Comment: Gotcha thanks, had a brain fart I should have realized it starts counting at zero like arrays always do.

Answer (score 4):

First you will need to keep track how full your `buffer` already is:

```
size_t buffer_length = 0;
```

Then you can just use `memcpy` to copy your data:

```
memcpy(buffer + buffer_length, data + offset, bytes_to_copy);
```

Comment: When declaring buffer_length I wouldn't need to make it equal to some sort of counter since that number would be variable as it grows?

Comment: @Stavros_S I didn't put it there, but you would probably increment it by `bytes_to_copy`.

Comment: Ok, and offset I'm guessing is the index in which I want to start the range from?

Comment: @Stavros_S Yes it is.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize concatenating the two would work like that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure you need an array with dynamic size then look at

```
void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
```

In this case 'buffer' should be defined as a pointer, not as a fixed size array, then you will allocate some initial size and reallocate as needed.

The realloc solution is scalable to any size of array. However, if you are sure that 1400 bytes is biggest size you will ever need, then defining that on stack will make no harm.

Comment: This not Really answer To the question (which has no Dynamic memory allocation). If You want to make This a decent answer, provide complete Alternative Solution.

Comment: @alexeypolo the void *ptr would be the pointer to the array or in this case data[] right?

Comment: @Stavros_S No, it would be pointer to memory allocated with *malloc()*. Which is why this answer needs expanding.